# Normal Passport Application to Tatkal Application

Tags: indian-citizens, passports

I applied for the renewal of my Indian passport on 11th December. My passport is due to expire in May 2020. I submitted a tatkal application but the passport officer at PSK said that I cannot apply under tatkal scheme due to change in appearance and he converted my application to normal. I wasn't aware of this and agreed with what he said.

Is it possible to visit RPO and change my application from normal to tatkal as I am supposed to fly back to Germany on 27th December and the online status still says: "Physical police verification pending". I read some cases online where people were able to convert their application from normal to tatkal. Is there anything that I can do to expedite the process?

P.S. The police verification is already done but the online status is not updated.

Comment: Mention location also. For example, in Kerala, due to e-verification from police side, even normal application will be processed and you will get passport in 5 days or so.

Comment: The location is Lucknow RPO